# Relativity question: frequency shift under constant acceleration

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, gravitational-redshift

Okay, my buddy tells me this:

Let there be a starship, ovoid, and me and my buddy stand each at the extremities of the ship, him below the roof, me on the floor.

We start a journey and the ship accelerates at a constant rate, let's say $1g$, in the direction of the axis of the ship.

*My buddy says*: since the ship is accelerating, when he strobe (on off on off) a light from the room, back to me, at a frequency $F$, I'll see a shifted frequency $F' = F + \delta f$.

If he switches the light at $1Hz$, I'll see $1.01Hz$ for instance.

*My take on the thing* tells me that in this case, there's no shift: we're both immobile in our referential, and the light will travel at $c$ in this referential.

Who's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of the [equivalence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) the experiment you describe is the same as if the two of you were standing at different heights on Earth. Specifically, it's a form of the [Pound-Rebka experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment), which experimentally verified that the frequency does indeed change.

It happens because time is moving at a different rate for the two of you. Whoever is standing below (i.e. would be hit by a dropped object from the other person) experiences time moving more slowly. Suppose the upper experimenter shines a light down at frequency $F$. That means the upper experiment will count $F$ cycles of the light in one second as measured by their wristwatch. Because the lower experimenter's watch is running more slowly the lower experiment counts more than $F$ cycles in a second measured on their watch, so the light appears blue shifted. By the same argument, if the lower experimenter shines a light up, the upper experimenter will see it red shifted.